# Attempt to arrange array elements in descending sequence (returning garbage values)

Tags: c

I wrote to program in C to attempt to print array elements in descending order. I wrote a nested loop which would find the maximum element of the array and the value of the element would be set to later 0. This process would be repeated for all the elements. However, in the output, I am getting the first 2-3 values as desired but the remaining values are garbage. Any suggestions?

```
int main() {
  int i, j, n, k;
  scanf("%d\n", &n);
  int a[100], b[100];

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int max = a[i];

    for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
      if (a[j] > max) {
        max = a[j];
        b[i] = max;
      }
    }

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
      printf("%d", a[k]);
      if (a[k] == b[i]) {
        a[k] = 0;
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%d ", b[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you only set `b[i] = max;` when you find a new `max`, but since you initialized `max` to be `a[i]` it could happen that it already holds the maximum value. So the `if` never executes, therefore `b[i]` is not written and there's garbage value in it. You should move this line from the `if` after that `for` loop.

Another issue is that you initialize `j` with `i` in this loop. You should initialize it to `0`.

The changed part:

```
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if (a[j] > max) {
        max = a[j];
      }
    }

    b[i] = max;
```